# Como localizar um arquivo sem especificar pasta/drive em bat ou lua?

Tags: cmd, batch, lua, bat

Como localizar um arquivo e guardá-lo em uma variável?

Vou usa-lo para leitura (essa parte já está resolvida), porém, quero localizar sem especificar pasta/drive, como por exemplo **`.\Arquivo.txt`**.

Já tentei isso, só que não funciona quando vai fazer a leitura...

Preciso disso, visto que, se fosse digitar o diretório completo, funcionaria em meu computador, porém, em outro não teria sucesso, já que o nome de pasta/caminho/diretórios, não seriam os mesmos.

Como fazer isso em **`bat`** ou **lua**?

Answer (score 1):

> - **Update v2** *Passando **parâmetro (lua.log)** e **inserção/input (lua.txt)**...*

---

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
rem :: Abaixo descritivo das variáveis relativas aos arquivos:
rem :: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem :: Arquivo passado no argumento/parâmetro arquivo parâmetro
rem :: variável nome do arquivo via arquivo.bat lua.txt (%~1) = !_arg!
rem :: variável caminho drive/pasta e sem o nome do arquivo   = !_path_arg!
rem :: variável caminho drive/pasta/arquivo com nome completo = !_full_arg!
rem :: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem :: variáveis do arquivo passado no input via comando set /p:
rem :: variável nome do arquivo via arquivo.bat lua.log (%~1) = !_input!
rem :: variavel caminho drive/pasta e sem o nome do arquivo   = !_path_input!
rem :: variavel caminho drive/pasta/arquivo com nome completo = !_full_input!
rem :: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**<kbd>[`Q395923.cmd`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/395923/como-localizar-um-arquivo-sem-especificar-pasta-drive-em-bat-ou-lua/396363#396363)</kbd>**

---

```ps1
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

2>nul >nul chcp 850 & title Q395923 & cls & echo/ 
for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do set _drv=!_drv!, %%f
set "_drv=!_drv: =!" & echo/ & set /p "_arq= Favor informar o nome do arquivo: " & set _lf=^

<nul 2>nul & set "_msg=Definindo as variavei relativas ao arquivo" & cls & set "_input=%~1"
cls & set "_drv=!_drv:~1!" & set "_sys=%windir%\system32" & call :~[ && goto :?)

:^[
echo/!_lf!Procurando pelo arquivo %~1 nos drivers: !_drv!^... !_lf!
for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('!_sys!\mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do (
     for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%F in ('cd /d %%f ^& cd\ ^& !_sys!\where /r .\ "!_%%/!" 2^>nul') do (
         set "_%2=%%~nxF" && set "_path_%2=%%~dpF" && set "_full_%2=%%~fF" && echo/ !_msg! !_%%/!^...
         echo/!_lf! Arquivo: !_%%~/! !_lf! Caminho: !_path_%%/! &echo/ Completo: !_full_%%/! & exit /b))

:~[
(for %%/ in (arq,input)do call :^[ "!_%%/!" %%/) && exit /b 

:?)
echo/!_lf! As suas próximas açoes/comandos seguiram abaixo desta linha!!!..
```

---

> - **Update** *baseado nos comentários*...
>     **Início do Update!**

Considerando que entendi vossos comentários, então vais chamar o **`bat`** passando esses **argumentos**:

```ps1
[Arquivo.bat] [lua compilador(a variável do arquivo lua q também vou ter q achar)] [arq(a variável do arquivo txt)]
```

---

> - **Portando** para o **`bat`** passando **argumentos** sem passar o **MD5**:

---

```ps1
 %0 = [Arquivo.bat]          
 %1 = [lua compilador(a variável do arquivo lua q também vou ter q achar)]
 %2 = [arq(a variável do arquivo txt)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %0          %1           %2   
Q395923.cmd "buscar_arq" "algum_txt"
```

---

> - O **código** em **`bat`** sem **hash/MD5**, ficaria:

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```ps1
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title < nul && title Q395923 & echo/ 

set "_file=%~1" && set "_txt=%~2" & echo/ Procurando pelo arquivo: !_file!... & echo/

for /f %%f in ('%windir%\system32\mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do for /f %%F in ('cd /d "%%f" ^& cd\ ^& %windir%\system32\where /r .\ "!_file!" 2^>nul')do (
   set "_lua=%%F" && set "_pasta=%%~dpF" && goto :^)
          )

:^)
if "!_lua!/." == "/." (echo/ Arquivo "%~1" n localizado^!! & goto :eof) else (echo/  Arquivo: !_file! &echo/    Pasta: !_pasta!) 

rem:: variável !_lua! vai armazenar o caminho completo buscado no bat = %1 no bat
rem:: variável !_txt! vai armazenar o arquivo.txt, passado no comando = %2 no bat
```

---

> - **Portando** para o **`bat`** passando **argumentos** com o **MD5**:

---

```ps1
 %0 = [Arquivo.bat]          
 %1 = [lua compilador(a variável do arquivo lua q também vou ter q achar)]
 %2 = [arq(a variável do arquivo txt)]
 %3 = [Hash(MD5 do arquivo que busca encontrar)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %0          %1          %2                     %3
Q395923.cmd "buscar_arq" "algum_txt" "d3369d9f356dc5795a49ae2ecca5787a"
```

---

> - O **código** em **`bat`** com **hash/MD5**, ficaria:

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```ps1
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title < nul && title Q395923 & echo/ 

set "_file=%~1" && set "_txt=%~2" && set "_md5=%~3" & echo/ Procurando pelo arquivo: !_file!... & echo/

for /f %%f in ('%windir%\system32\mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do for /f %%F in ('cd /d "%%f" ^& cd\ ^& %windir%\system32\where /r .\ "!_file!" 2^>nul')do (
   set "_lua=%%F" && set "_pasta=%%~dpF" && for /f delims^=^ ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%windir%\system32\certutil -hashfile "!_file!" md5^|find /v ":"')do if "%%~i" == "!_md5!" goto :^)
          )

:^)
if "!_lua!/." == "/." (echo/ Arquivo "%~1" n localizado^!! & goto :eof) else (echo/  Arquivo: !_file! &echo/    Pasta: !_pasta! &echo/ Hash MD5: !_md5!) 

rem:: variável !_lua! vai armazenar o caminho completo buscado no bat = %1 no bat
rem:: variável !_txt! vai armazenar o arquivo.txt, passado no comando = %2 no bat
rem:: variável !_md5! vai armazenar o hash/MD5 do arquivo que desejas = %3 no bat
```

---

> - **Update** *baseado nos comentários*...
>     **Fim do Update!**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Obs.:** Uma busca no computador (todos os driver/pastas/subpastas) vai demorar...

---

Para procurar um arquivo (***arquivo_alvo.ext***), sugiro primeiro obter o **MD5** do arquivo alvo, para verificar se o MD5 do arquivo encontrado pelo **bat** seja o **mesmo** que **procuras**, evitando encontrar algum arquivo com o mesmo nome mas seu conteúdo difere do arquivo desejado.

---

Para obter o **MD5** com o **`certutil.exe`** use o código abaixo, que vai exibir na tela a **`string`** do **`MD5`** e também vai mover uma cópia para seu **`Crtl+C`**, facilitando colar no seu arquivo **`bat`**:

```ps1
@for /f delims^=^ ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%windir%\system32\certutil -hashfile "c:\pasta\subpast\arquivo_alvo.ext" md5^|find /v ":"')do (
    @echo/%%i & echo/%%i|clip
    )
```

**Obs.:** **Certiutil.exe** já vem com Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1, 10 e versões server.

Para localiza o arquivo e sem saber em que drive ou pasta este arquivo possa estar....

1) Use do comando **`mountvol`** para listar **todos** os drivers disponíveis no sistema

2) Passando a saída do **`mountvol`** dentro de um looping **`for`**, podemos buscar o 
 arquivo desejado com o comando **`where`* em cada drive e suas sub-pastas

3) Sendo encontrado pelo comando **`where`**, vamos passar a saída deste comando para o com **`certutil`** e, assim, obtermos o MD5 do arquivo

4) Usando um **`if`**, podemos verificar se o arquivo encontrado tem a soma **`MD5`** igual a do arquivo **`buscado/desejado`**.

```ps1
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title < nul && title Q395923
set "_file=arquivo_alvo.ext" && set "_hash=d3369d9f356dc5795a49ae2ecca5787a"

for /f %%f in ('mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do for /f %%F in ('cd /d %%f ^& cd\ ^& where /r .\ "!_file!"')do >nul set "_lua=%%F" && (
     for /f delims^=^ ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%windir%\system32\certutil -hashfile "%%~F" md5^|find /v ":"')do if "%%~i" == "!_hash!" (
         set "_path_file=%%~dpF" & goto :^))
         )
echo/ Arquivo "!_file!" n localizado^!! & goto :eof 

:^)
echo/ Arquivo: "!_file!" &echo/   Pasta: "!_path_file!" & echo/    Hash: "!_hash!"
```

---

- **Sem verificar** se o **MD5** bate com o **arquivo** que procuras:

Para localizar um arquivo sem saber a pasta e estando no mesmo drive:

---

```ps1
cd\ & where /r "." "arquivo.ext"
```

Dentro de um bat usando for:

---

```ps1
@echo off & cd\ 

for /f %%f in (`where /r "." "arquivo.ext"`)do set "_path_file=%%~dpf"
echo/%_path_file%
```

Comment: e nao estando no mesmo drive

Comment: @ElonNeto 1º código faz isso, considera q n sabe qual drive/pasta, busca em todos os drivers/pastas.

Comment: ok vlw muito obg msm

Comment: como faço para passar para uma variavel? e utilizar por exemplo assim: `lua compilador(a variavel do arquivo lua q tambem vou ter q achar) arq(a variavel do arquivo txt) `

Comment: eita, tendi n... isso em bat ou lua?

Comment: bat, eh q o usuario ai passar um arquivo, ai eu tenho q achar o arquivo lua e esse arquivo q ele vai passar

Comment: sim sim, mas eu ja sei o nome do programa em lua, quero passar o caminho dele para uma variavel e depois usar para abri-lo

Comment: ta blz, me passa teu discord? que ai agente se fala por la tenho que sair daq 1 hr

Comment: ue discord, sabe oq eh nn?